# Python List Comprehension for MmF

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How would I express this in list comprehension?

```
for x in unsat_links:
      for i in x.fol:
        if i in sat_links:
          x.fol.remove(i)
```

I know I am not supposed to do this, but I want to rewrite it so it updates the list by removing the element based on the condition.

I tried doing a while loop but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Why would you do this, if you don’t understood how and the existing solution works?

Comment: What is up with the inconsistent indentation?

Comment: @PeterMortensen not op but probably a copy paste thing, all of it is indented 2 spaces, but if you start the copy at the first for loop, you lose all the spaces on that line

Answer (score 1):

```
((x.fol.remove(i) for i in x.fol if i in sat_links) for x in unsat_links)
```

Keep in mind, the list is basically useless at this point. All you are doing is code golfing. You also might as well use generators.

This also changes the size of `x.fol` during iteration which is bad and should probably be avoided.

The best way of doing this is with `set` subtraction if you do not care about order and duplicates.

Comment: how would I implement this with set subtraction?

Comment: Something like: set(i for i in x.fol for x in unsat_links) - set(sat_links)

Not 100% sure about that code though